# Ubuntu 12 heating problem in Acer 5755g Laptop

Tags: overheating

I installed recent Ubuntu version in my Acer 5755G laptop, it is over-heating. The laptop is in good condition,it'll not get heat while using windows 7. I think the problem with the graphics card. But as I'm new to Ubuntu i don't know how to solve the problem. So please someone help me.

Laptop Configurations:

- i5 second Generation
- 750GB HDD
- 2GB nVIDIA graphics card
- 4GB RAM

Comment: is your computer a hybrid graphics solution? You should check to get the correct graphics drivers for the machine, as I would guess that both cards (intel and dedicated) are running. If you are using the open source drivers, you should be able to use vga_switcheroo. What's the output of `cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`?

Answer (score 0):

NVidia graphics card eats up a lot of power. You need [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html#Ubuntu) to control power consumption. Installing it helped reduce my core temperatures and increase battery-life to about 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

**Turn off the graphics card from BIOS** 

I am also using **ubutnu 14.04LTS**. Heating problem is almost all linux os has for those laptop having two graphics (integrated and dedicated like nvidia).
So,
The solution is **turn off the graphics card from BIOS** setting. This works for me and gives almost **3.5 hours battery** backup and no more heating.

Tell me if it works for U.

Answer (score 0):

## Use the [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc)

Mine is an Acer Aspire E5-573G laptop and nothing else worked to control the CPU fan, but [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki/First-steps). I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. The exact profile for my model is missing, but nbfc worked fine with another similar profile (Acer Aspire E5-575G). If you don't know which profile to use, you can try:
`mono nbfc.exe config -r`

You will need the latest mono version to build it on Ubuntu 18.04, so don't forget to read [How to build NBFC on ubuntu](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki/How-to-build-NBFC#ubuntu).

Also I edit the default profile to turn the fan policy more aggressive.

Comment: More details here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1267308/252684