# step by step solution to fan problem in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, lenovo, fan, fancontrol

I quite recently replaced my laptop fan and was functioning, at least fine though the speed seems to be low in Ubuntu. Now I think after updating the system (not sure) fan does not seem working.

```
$sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +76.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +76.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 2:       +77.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
```

How do I check is there any hardware issue ?

If not how do I resolve it ?

I'd appreciate if I can get step by step instructions to analyse the problem and find a solution.

As a result to `ftws fan`, thanx to @Lnux:

```
$ fwts fan
Running 1 tests, results appended to results.log
Test: Simple Fan Tests.                                                     
  Check fan status.                                       5 passed             
  Load system, check CPU fan status.
```

As given in [How do I know my fan is working in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482766/how-do-i-know-my-fan-is-working-in-ubuntu):

`sudo apt-get install hardinfo`

In `System Profiler and Benchmark`, I see a blank page in `sensor` option.

**Steps tried so far:**

As give [Fancontrol under Ubuntu 14.04 – resolving /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed](http://iandw.net/2014/10/12/fancontrol-under-ubuntu-14-04-resolving-usrsbinpwmconfig-there-are-no-pwm-capable-sensor-modules-installed/),

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

replacing:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax"
```

update the boot configuration:

```
sudo update-grub

sudo pwmconfig
```

This gives:

```
$ sudo pwmconfig
# pwmconfig revision 5857 (2010-08-22)
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

**System Details:**

```
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit
Lenovo Ideapad z560
```

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [GeForce 310M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 392d
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Output of `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  nvidia-331                                      340.96-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                    Transitional package for nvidia-331
ii  nvidia-340                                      340.96-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                    NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.96
ii  nvidia-340-uvm                                  340.96-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                    Transitional package for nvidia-340
ii  nvidia-common                                   1:0.2.44.2                                 Find obsolete NVIDIA drivers
ii  nvidia-libopencl1-340                           340.96-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                    NVIDIA OpenCL Driver and ICD Loader library
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-340                           340.96-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                    NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                    0.5~hybrid0.0.3                            Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                 331.20-0ubuntu0.0.1                        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Comment: I would try `nvidia-304` for this adapter. `340` in some cases is not good for these adapters. Try `sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia.*' && sudo apt-get install nvidia-304`. Then reboot.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have done it. Does not seem to solve the problem. How do I check ?

Comment: Check the temps. If that does not work, install 340 back.

Comment: @Pilot6 nope, temp. is still the same. I'm confused, Is my fan really working ?.What do i understand from `ftws fan` output ?. Atleast my fan speed up switch is not working

Comment: @Pilot6 could u pls confirm whether it is due to hardware problem ?

Comment: Are you sure you did not press the 'Smart Noise Control button' and put the fan into silent mode? Also did you install and configure lm-sensors after editing your /etc/default/grub and running pwmconfig?