# CPU overheating on Ubuntu 16.04 (MSI GE40)

Tags: laptop, intel, cpu, overheating, temperature

For the past 2 years I've been trying to definitively switch my laptop from Windows to Linux, but it's been a constant struggle. I have a MSI GE40 with Intel i7 4800MQ CPU.

I just installed (2017-03-25) Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS in hope that all my problems were solved, and apparently, most of them are, but this one still remains.

When I boot on Ubuntu, my CPU temperature is about 60º Celsius, after just 30 minutes of use (not a heavy use, just a browser with 2 or 3 tabs and a Terminal - loadaverage below 1) the temperature skyrocket to 87º Celsius. The notebook starts to become slow and very hot.

The command "sensors" were used in order to obtain the CPU temperature.

I did my homework, read posts and try a lot of commands, but none of them worked properly. The follow commands were executed:

sensors output 3 minutes of uptime

```
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +74.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +72.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +66.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +72.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +68.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +63.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

sensors output 9 minutes of uptime

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +84.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +81.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +76.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +81.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +78.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +74.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

After that, I ran a "dmesg", here is the output

```
[  448.586523] powercap intel-rapl:0: package locked by BIOS, monitoring onl
```

sensors output 17 minutes of uptime

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +89.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +85.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +85.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +85.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +84.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +80.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Another "dmesg" output:

```
[  993.126316] intel_powerclamp: Start idle injection to reduce power
```

Suddenly, loadaverage goes up and I got this on "top":

```
3372 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  54,8  0,0   1:04.68 kidle_inject/0                                                                          
 3376 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  54,8  0,0   1:09.30 kidle_inject/4                                                                          
 3378 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  54,8  0,0   1:10.24 kidle_inject/6                                                                          
 3374 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  54,5  0,0   1:08.29 kidle_inject/2                                                                          
 3379 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  54,5  0,0   1:10.29 kidle_inject/7                                                                          
 3375 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  53,1  0,0   1:07.95 kidle_inject/3                                                                          
 3377 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  49,8  0,0   1:06.50 kidle_inject/5                                                                          
 3373 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  47,2  0,0   1:02.87 kidle_inject/1
```

After a couple of minutes, loadaverage returns to normal and temperature drops a litte bit, but after 14 minutes, temperature is high again:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +87.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +84.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +80.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +84.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +80.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +80.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

And a lot a messages on "dmesg":

```
[ 1471.283752] CPU4: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 1471.283753] CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 1471.283765] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 1471.283766] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 1471.283766] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 1471.283769] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 1471.283770] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 1471.283771] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 1471.283772] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[ 1471.283773] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 1471.283779] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 1471.283780] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[ 1471.284740] CPU4: Core temperature/speed normal
[ 1471.284741] CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
[ 1471.284742] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 1471.284743] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 1471.284757] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 1471.284760] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 1471.284761] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 1471.284762] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 1471.284762] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 1471.284803] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 1473.935935] intel_powerclamp: Start idle injection to reduce power
[ 1759.514479] perf: interrupt took too long (2523 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79250
```

After that, the kidle_inject processes returned and never went away:

```
load average: 5,79, 5,18, 3,12
```

Since the notebook started to freeze, I rebooted on Windows, and to my surprise, after 2 or 3 minutes of uptime, the "Core Temp" output were this:

[Core Temp screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLn0S.png)

The same behavior happens with OpenSource or Proprietary CPU "drivers".
I also tried to "rmmod intel_powerclamp", but that just stopped the kidle_inject to happen again, the temperature still remains very high.

Any help is appreciated.

Some hardware info:

"lspci -v" output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: ie31200_edac

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: f6000000-f70fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000f1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at f7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Memory at f7a14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at f7a00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at f7a1d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at f7a10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: cf200000-cf3fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000cf400000-00000000cf5fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: f7900000-f79fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000c000-0000cfff
    Memory behind bridge: f7800000-f78fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f7a1b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] HM87 Express LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at f7a1a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 3
    Memory at f7a19000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106M [GeForce GTX 760M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GK106M [GeForce GTX 760M]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at f7900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at d000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx

04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at c000 [size=256]
    Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723ae
    Kernel modules: rtl8723ae
```

cat /proc/cpu output: (snipped)

```
processor   : 7
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 60
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4800MQ CPU @ 2.70GHz
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0x8
cpu MHz     : 3546.881
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 7
initial apicid  : 7
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
bugs        :
bogomips    : 5387.59
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

lsmod output:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  0
ccm                    20480  1
bbswitch               16384  0
rtsx_usb_ms            20480  0
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         28672  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_usb_ms
rtsx_usb               24576  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
bnep                   20480  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
msi_wmi                16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 msi_wmi
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             192512  0
kvm                   598016  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  2
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 ablk_helper,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
intel_cstate           16384  0
arc4                   16384  2
rtl8723ae              86016  0
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8723ae
uvcvideo               90112  0
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723ae
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723ae
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723ae
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
mac80211              761856  2 rtl_pci,rtlwifi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45056  1
videodev              180224  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
btintel                16384  1 btusb
cfg80211              581632  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
bluetooth             557056  31 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
snd_soc_rt5640        118784  0
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
snd_soc_core          233472  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           86016  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
ie31200_edac           16384  0
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
edac_core              53248  1 ie31200_edac
mei_me                 40960  0
snd_pcm               110592  7 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core,snd_soc_rt5640,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_soc_core
lpc_ich                24576  0
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
shpchp                 36864  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    86016  23 snd_compress,snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
elan_i2c               36864  0
dw_dmac                16384  0
wmi                    16384  2 msi_wmi,mxm_wmi
dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0
8250_dw                16384  0
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
snd_soc_sst_match      16384  1 snd_soc_sst_acpi
mac_hid                16384  0
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
soc_button_array       16384  0
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
nvidia_uvm            647168  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
autofs4                40960  2
hid_logitech_hidpp     28672  0
hid_logitech_dj        20480  0
usbhid                 53248  0
nvidia_drm             49152  7
nvidia_modeset        790528  4 nvidia_drm
i915                 1310720  3
nvidia              12144640  68 nvidia_modeset,nvidia_uvm
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        167936  2 i915,nvidia_drm
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               139264  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  3
libahci                32768  1 ahci
drm                   368640  6 i915,nvidia_drm,drm_kms_helper
alx                    36864  0
mdio                   16384  1 alx
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   122880  6 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
sdhci_acpi             16384  0
video                  40960  2 msi_wmi,i915
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
fjes                   28672  0
```

Comment: What do you get for `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` and `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`. Have you considered thermald?

Comment: It looks like `thermald` is already installed, and trying its hardest to control the temps. Did you customize thermal-conf.xml? How old is your laptop? Is it in a very dusty environment? Do you ever hear the fans come on? I noticed this error... "powercap intel-rapl:0: package locked by BIOS, monitoring only". Are there some settings that you need to check in your BIOS? Do you have `intel-microcode` installed?

Comment: @DougSmythies, I get scaling_driver = intel_pstate (I tried to disabled it editing kernel CMD on Grub2, but without any success, I get the same behavior), and my scaling_governor=powersave.
Thermald is already runnig, and not, I didn't change anything on the config file.

Comment: @heynnema, I didn't customize thermald config file. My laptop is 5 years old, but my room is not dusty and like I said, on Windows the temperature is very low, even with a lot more programs running. I did notice the "power cap..." message, so I booted on BiOS but no success in finding anything related to the error. I'll check the "intel-microcode" that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Even though your room is not dusty, I would recommend that you clean your vent paths and fans in your Laptop at least once per year.

Sometimes the default `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` doesn't react soon enough. Save your original somewhere and try this one, noting that it has a ridiculously low threshold temperature, just for testing. Once you are satisfied that it solves your problem, raise the threshold temperature to something more reasonable, perhaps in steps:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
use "man thermal-conf.xml" for details
-->

<!-- BEGIN -->
<ThermalConfiguration>
        <Platform>
                <Name>Overide CPU default passive</Name>
                <ProductName>*</ProductName>
                <Preference>QUIET</Preference>
                <ThermalZones>
                        <ThermalZone>
                                <Type>cpu</Type>
                                <TripPoints>
                                        <TripPoint>
                                                <Temperature>55000</Temperature>
                                                <type>passive</type>
                                        </TripPoint>
                                </TripPoints>
                        </ThermalZone>
                </ThermalZones>
        </Platform>
</ThermalConfiguration>
<!-- END -->
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I took so long to respond.
Tried to alter ThermalD config, but, it didn't make any difference.
I ran a lot of tests and things are a better, but not solved.
I turned the notebook on, logged in and wait without doing nothing, just monitoring temperature. After 1h no more than 60 C. Opened Firefox, after 1 minute, CPU at 75C, 5 minutes later with 2 tabs opened 85C
Altering the video card config in Nvidia Settings I selected the software to use just Intel video card and them, rebooted.
Just by doing that I was able to open multiple firefox tabs while watching video on VLC for 50m.

Comment: @DougSmythies your thermal-conf.xml has no definitions for `<ThermalSensors>`, so it can't really determine what the current temps are. Search here on AU for `user:4272 thermald` and you'll find my other answers, and example code, for thermald.

Comment: @heynnema : O.K. All I can say is that it worked fine for me.

Comment: @heynnema : I re-installed thermald and ran it with the exact same configuration file as above (well, I lowered the tripoint to 45 degrees). It worked just as expected. It does overshoot the first time, to 53 degrees, but settles nicely thereafter.

Comment: @DougSmythies Interesting. Want to have some fun? In `terminal`... do `sudo service thermald stop` then `sudo thermald --no-daemon --loglevel=debug` and watch it run in real time. Look for something where it must still be finding the temp sensors on its own. All of this data is a good basis for writing the xml file. Take note very early on if it says it can't find the xml file.

Comment: @heynnema : O.K. that all looks good. I see it parse the .xml file and do a bunch of stuff. Here is a segment from the monitor loop: `read_temperature sensor ID 2` then `Sensor x86_pkg_temp :temp 43000` then `pref 0 type 2 temp 43000 trip 45000`

Comment: @DougSmythies fair enough. It is finding the temp sensors on its own. Watching thermald in --no-daemon mode is kind of interesting, huh?

Answer (score 0):

## [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc) can help you

I've an Acer Aspire E5-573G and nothing else worked to control the CPU fan, but [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki/First-steps). I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. The exact profile for my model is missing, but nbfc worked fine with another similar profile (Acer Aspire E5-575G). If you don't know which profile to use, you can try:
`mono nbfc.exe config -r`

Also I edit the default profile to turn the fan policy more agressive.

Comment: See how to build and use: https://askubuntu.com/a/1267308/252684

Answer (score 0):

This problem is still valid on newer MSI laptops. This is obviously not related to dust or anything like that, it's because *Dragon Center*, MSI's Windows-only utility, configures the CPU package appropriately for dynamic frequency scaling, which by default is atrociously configured. Since you're not on Windows you can't use Dragon Center.

Now mind you, why not configuring the CPU package right from BIOS startup, with at least some more conservative value ? I don't know actually... maybe because that would mean acknowledging that earth isn't flat, and there is a world beyond Windows ? Yes, possibly.

So, of course there must be a way to configure the CPU properly, but since MSI doesn't publish any specs regarding this, and doesn't support Linux, we're left naked and to guess by ourselves. I don't have a problem with a company not officially supporting Linux, but hiding OS-independent specs that would permit people to have working hardware on, heck, whatever OS one wants to use, that should be punished... and certainly will be some day, the sooner the better.

Now about the practical details, CPU package configuration seems to be managed via the laptop's embedded controller, seemingly at EC address 0xD2, but I don't know enough about this yet, and for now the only option is to disable *Intel Turbo Boost*, by doing this : `echo 1 >/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo`

I will come back as I get more info. While this is not being addressed, my advice to Linux users looking towards MSI is : beware, you have been warned !