# How to decrease computer temperature - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

The laptop temperature is constantly high.

This is the output for command `sensors`:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +85.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp2:         +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp3:        +64.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp4:        +68.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp5:        +37.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp6:       +114.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +82.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +80.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +78.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

I have an HP Probook 45 with i5.

How can I reduce its temperature?

Edit:

Output for `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` command:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: 64
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 question updated

Comment: Is the fan running?

Comment: In this case it is not OS related. Clean the cooler.

Comment: @Pilot6 It might be OS related..... I have an old laptop and the BIOS had a bug where the fan wouldn't run unless you booted a Windows OS. Updating to the latest BIOS fixed the issue.

Comment: You're about to burn up your computer. That's too hot. Are the fans starting at all? Does it get this hot in Windows? Install `intel-microcode` and `thermald`. Report back.

Comment: ps: also make sure you have the latest BIOS installed for your model.

Comment: `intel-microcode is already the newest version (3.20151106.1).` and `thermald is already the newest version (1.5-2ubuntu4).`

I don't have Windows installed on this machine.

Comment: The default thermald configuration will not keep your CPU temperatures low, it will only protect from very high temeratures. Try the thermald configuration I wrote for [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897217/cpu-overheating-on-ubuntu-16-04-msi-ge40/897856#897856).

Comment: @DougSmythies your thermal-conf.xml has no definitions for `<ThermalSensors>`, so it can't really determine what the current temps are. Search here on AU for `user:4272 thermald` and you'll find my other answers, and example code, for thermald.

Comment: @heynnema : All I can say is that it worked fine for me, and did exactly what I wanted.