# Ubuntu 18.04.1 not thermal throttling

Tags: kernel, cpu, overheating, temperature

I have a asus laptop (X705UDR), and installed ubuntu on it. However, I have some trouble with overheating under load, and after some investigation I noticed that, even when core temps reach 90+ degrees celcius, it still keeps turboing happily to 3.5-3.6 GHz (it's a 1.8GHz rated mobile processor), overheating the system fairly rapidly (~1-2 seconds).

I have tried installing TLP to see if it made the problem better, and although it seems to help with battery life, the overheating still occurs if I'm not carefull.

I also noticed that it will still sometimes thermal throttle, at least according to the kernel logs (from dmesg):

```
[ 2719.863917] CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 2719.863918] CPU4: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 2719.863919] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 2719.863920] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 2719.863921] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 2719.863922] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 2719.863923] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 2719.863924] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 2719.863926] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 2719.863933] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[ 2719.864930] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 2719.864931] CPU4: Core temperature/speed normal
[ 2719.864931] CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
[ 2719.864932] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 2719.864932] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 2719.864933] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 2719.864933] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 2719.864934] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 2719.864934] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 2719.864935] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
```

Not sure what the trigger is, but it suggests that it is at least possible to configure the kernel to do this properly. I also noticed, when checking the temp sensors, that it reports somewhat problematically high limits:

```
Package id 0:  +49.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +48.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +49.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +48.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

I am fairly sure (from observations) that crit is the hardware cutoff temperature, however then high is somewhat weird. Is this the number that the linux kernel uses to determine whether to thermal throttle and if so, how do I change it. If not, is there some other way to configure the temperatures at which the kernel decides to clock down the processor cores? I have found some scripts in old answers that claim to do this, but I would rather not rely on something like that if at all possible.

As a temporary measure, I have figured out that I can completely disable turbo boosting. However, this also comes at a severe performance penalty so I would like a better solution if possible.

**EDIT:** As a temporary measure, I have figured out I can decrease intel pstate's max_perf_pct to limit how agressively it turbos. This limits peak performance but does deal with the overheating without sacrificing sustained performance too much.

Comment: Can you improve the cooling? For example: remove dust from the interior, clear the way for air to get into and out of the laptop, get a 'laptop cooling pad'.

Comment: Try thernald, but suggest tossing out the default config file and use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897217/cpu-overheating-on-ubuntu-16-04-msi-ge40/897856#897856) one instead. There is bunch more test results using that config file [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2408458&page=3&p=13824779#post13824779).

Comment: @DougSmythies: Tried that config, thermald complains about it not knowing the cpu thermal zone. Replaced it by the sensor name that i know from testing is the package temp, but that also does nothing. Also have some trouble getting thermald to even use the config, need to start it manually with explicit --config-file option

Comment: @davidv1992 : What is your CPU make and model? `grep name /proc/cpuinfo` . I looked up your computer and thought it would be an Intel "i" something type, which should work.

Comment: @DougSmythies: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz