# Clock CPU at frequencies other than 'available frequencies' on Xubuntu with Ryzen processor

Tags: xubuntu, acpi, cpufreq, amd-ryzen

CPU:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 11
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 23
model       : 96
model name  : AMD Ryzen 5 4600H with Radeon Graphics
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x8600104
cpu MHz     : 1397.266
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 12
core id     : 6
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 13
initial apicid  : 13
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 16
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 cqm rdt_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local clzero irperf xsaveerptr rdpru wbnoinvd arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif umip rdpid overflow_recov succor smca
bugs        : sysret_ss_attrs spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass
bogomips    : 5988.99
TLB size    : 3072 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro [13] [14]
```

OS:

Xubuntu 20.10, everything is updated to latest and greatest as of 01/06.

Kernel:

```
$ uname -r
5.8.0-34-generic
```

With this linux distro and CPU combo, I have these available frequencies: 3.00 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.40 GHz.  Example:

```
$ cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 1.40 GHz - 3.00 GHz
  available frequency steps:  3.00 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative userspace powersave ondemand performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 3.00 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: 3.00 GHz (asserted by call to hardware)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    Boost States: 0
    Total States: 3
    Pstate-P0:  3000MHz
    Pstate-P1:  1700MHz
    Pstate-P2:  1400MHz
```

I can't run a frequency of.. lets say 2.9GHz or even 800MHz for example.  **I want granularity on what frequency my CPU is running at.**

I've tried [ZenStates](https://github.com/r4m0n/ZenStates-Linux/blob/master/zenstates.py):

```
$ ./zenstates.py -p 2 -f 20 -d 8 -v 66 --enable
$ ./zenstates.py -l
P0 - Enabled - FID = 78 - DID = 8 - VID = 35 - Ratio = 30.00 - vCore = 1.21875
P1 - Enabled - FID = 66 - DID = C - VID = 60 - Ratio = 17.00 - vCore = 0.95000
P2 - Enabled - FID = 20 - DID = 8 - VID = 66 - Ratio = 8.00 - vCore = 0.91250
P3 - Disabled
P4 - Disabled
P5 - Disabled
P6 - Disabled
P7 - Disabled
C6 State - Package - Enabled
C6 State - Core - Enabled
```

Which works according to cpupower (not really):

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 1.40 GHz - 3.00 GHz
  available frequency steps:  3.00 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative userspace powersave ondemand performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 3.00 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: 1.70 GHz (asserted by call to hardware)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    Boost States: 0
    Total States: 3
    Pstate-P0:  3000MHz
    Pstate-P1:  1700MHz
    Pstate-P2:  800MHz
```

But you can't actually change to 800MHz with cpupower.  Lowest you can go is 1.4GHz.

I've also tried `cpufrequtils`, it does nothing.

I've tried `ignore_ppc`.

I am currently experiencing an interesting bug relating to CPU frequency:

My CPU is running at 400MHz after waking up from a days long suspend.  How is that possible?

**Current CPU frequency** says 3GHz, which is wrong.  I know this because of two reasons:

1.

```
watch -n.1 'cat /proc/cpuinfo|grep MHz'

$ cat /proc/cpuinfo|grep MHz
cpu MHz     : 399.221
cpu MHz     : 399.183
cpu MHz     : 399.007
cpu MHz     : 399.201
cpu MHz     : 399.221
cpu MHz     : 399.216
cpu MHz     : 399.113
cpu MHz     : 399.198
cpu MHz     : 398.940
cpu MHz     : 399.163
cpu MHz     : 399.199
cpu MHz     : 399.072
```

2. My computer is running sluggish and I'm not running anything that could cause the computer to run slower than normal.

Attempts to go back to normal:

1.

```
cpupower frequency-set --max 3GHz
cpupower frequency-set --governor ondemand
```

and

```
cpupower frequency-set --governor performance
```

According to cpupower, the commands worked.  But my computer was still running at 400MHz.

2. I rebooted into BIOS, made no changes, exited BIOS, booted into Xubuntu, CPU frequency was still 400MHz.

This below fixed the problem:

**I rebooted into windows**, rebooted back into Xubuntu, and CPU frequencies were back to normal.

It may be tlp's fault.  Heres my tlp config `/etc/tlp.conf`, I'm only listing whats not commented:

```
TLP_ENABLE=1
TLP_PERSISTENT_DEFAULT=1
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=1
WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=on
WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=on
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1
```

[Here is a guy who had the same CPU suspend bug.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298627/ubuntu-20-10-ryzen-2700x-stuck-at-549mhz-after-resume-from-suspend)  [Here is another guy, same bug.](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/my-cpu-frequencies-got-messed-up-somehow-and-i-cant-figure-out-why/18534)

Comment: This question sounds like *two* questions: 1 ⇢ You want to control the frequency your CPU runs at and 2 ⇢ Your CPU runs at a fixed, low frequency after waking from suspend. Is this correct?

Comment: Its just #1.  I mentioned #2 because the bug magically achieved #1 (but without control over the frequency).

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to have the CPU cores run at very specific speeds, you *might* be able to use [the solution to this question over here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300409/applications-are-ignoring-exceeding-user-set-cpu-frequencies-limitations-20-04/1300424#1300424). Basically, it works like this:

1. Install `cpufreq` from [Ubuntu’s repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/cpufrequtils)
2. Run `cpufreq-info` to see what governors and limits are in place already
3. Call `cpufreq-set --cpu 0 —min 800MHz --max 800MHz` for each CPU core on your machine, setting the MHz (or GHz) value to your desired limit

I have never tried to govern the CPU with a hard minimum, so do not know for certain if you can limit your system with the level of granularity that you are looking for.

Comment: Is there a difference between the 'Ubuntu Repository' website as opposed to synaptic?  The version on the website is the same as the version in synaptic.  Version 008-2.  I installed the version from synaptic, tried your suggestion (I've never specified --cpu before) and it didn't work.

Comment: @JeffLuyet Both are the same. Synaptic is a graphical interface to access the Ubuntu repository (and other repositories manually added by the user)