# CPU thermal Thermal Throttling issue

Tags: hardware

I yust installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Surface Laptop 1 and I have Thermal Throttling issues.

I tried everything from using the tee command:

```
echo 65 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct
```

To using this fix: https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Surface-Laptop 1

But noting seems to work for me

My specs are:

Core i5-7200U

8Gb of ram

Intel HD 620 Graphics

Comment: Are you sure it is thermal throttling and not some other throttling such as power limits? Try limiting "max_perf_pct" even more. Try disabling turbo. If your CPU frequencies are stuck low, there might be some other reason. If I ever use thermald, I prefer a very simple config file, such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897217/cpu-overheating-on-ubuntu-16-04-msi-ge40/897856#897856)

Comment: I prefer to use turbostat (linux-tools-common package) to monitor power, temp, CPU frequency. Such as: `sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt --interval 6`

Comment: How can I exacly disable Turbo boost. Vesides Thermald dosent seem to use the scrips that I provided under /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml for some reason

Comment: Also thank you for your help

Comment: see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/619875/disabling-intel-turbo-boost-in-ubuntu/620114#620114) for disabling turbostat after boot. You might find you need to disable it before boot, in BIOS, at least as a test. Is the thermald service running on your computer? `sudo systemctl status thermald`

Comment: Yes the service is indeed running, and no, I cannot disable Turbo boost from bios on this Laptop: Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-10-18 07:43:01 EST; 3h 30min ago

Comment: It has been a long time since I have used thermald. I revived my old work on my test 20.04 Ubuntu server and it is working just as it did before. It is a rather terrible temperature servo, but that can dealt with later, if you can get functional with it.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I had to switch to Windows because of how unusable it was, I've never encountered a Computer like this. Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Not an surface user, but I was affected by this:

https://phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Platform-Profiles-Axboe
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-ACPI-Platform-Profile

If you are using a linux kernel >= 5.1 check if modifying `/sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile` solves your problem

note: there is `/sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile_choices` showing possible values