# Heating Issues on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: overheating

I am using Hp pavilion g series model and installed ubuntu 17.04 but it is over heating up to 89 c temperature  .is there any solution to reduce the temperature?
**My VGA is** 
0:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)

### Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [103c:1670]

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] [1002:6760]
    DeviceName: ATI SEYMOUR XT
**My Ram is**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1878        1387         116          49         374         231
Low:           1878        1762         116
High:             0           0           0
Swap:          1905          47        1858
```

Comment: check hardware system settings. My HP Notebook has a setting to run fan continuously.  This should keep you cool until you can figure out the thermal control.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Intel processors, make sure `intel-microcode` is installed... this will assure that you're running with the latest processor microcode:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get intel-microcode
```

Install `thermald`... to help control the temperature:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install thermald
```

`Thermald` comes with a default configuration file at `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` that will control most computers, but may need to be customized for some computers. See `man thermal-conf.xml` for some details and examples. Once one has modified the configuration file, stop `thermald` and restart it:

```
sudo service thermald restart
```

After installing thermald, I'd stop the `thermald` process, and run it manually as `sudo thermald --no-daemon` to watch its actions in real time. This real time info can be used to create your own customized thermal-conf.xml file. See `man thermald` for more information.

```
sudo service thermald stop
sudo thermald --no-daemon --loglevel=debug
```

You can search for `thermald` here on Ask Ubuntu to see what previous answers there are.

A good starter reference is at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues

Answer (score 0):

## Better try [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc)

I work with an Acer Aspire E5-573G and nothing else worked to manage my CPU fan, but [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki/First-steps). I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. The exact profile for my model is missing, but nbfc worked fine with another similar profile (Acer Aspire E5-575G). If you don't know which profile to use, you can try:
`mono nbfc.exe config -r`

You will need the latest mono version to build it on Ubuntu 18.04, so don't forget to read [How to build NBFC on ubuntu](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki/How-to-build-NBFC#ubuntu).

Also I edit the default profile to turn the fan policy more agressive.

Good luck.

Comment: To know how to build, see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1267308/252684